# Сглаживание X13-ARIMA-SEATS

Tags: математика, r, статистика, анализ-данных, статический-анализ

Какое минимальное количество наблюдений для использования данного метода? Есть примерно 20 наблюдений, сезонность визуально хорошо видна и выделяется, но из-за проблемы короткого ряда я не понимаю , насколько качественно произведено сглаживание.

Comment: А что на эту тему написано в документации?